# Entity Framework Error - The property 'id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

This is my first time using Entity Framework. I am using Entity Framework 6.0. I have two transaction tables:

1. Transaction (used to store each pallet)
2. ItemTransaction (used to store all items on pallet)

Both have id fields that are primary keys (auto generate).

I first create a Transaction when a user wants to create a new pallet with a selected product code:

```
                Transaction transaction = new Transaction
                {
                    productCode = _selectedTransaction.productCode,
                    productName = _selectedTransaction.productName,
                    LotCode = lotNumber,
                    palletNumber = serialInfo.PalletNumber,
                    Quantity = 0,
                    EntryDateTime = DateTime.Now,                   
                };

                myContext.Transactions.Add(transaction);
                myContext.SaveChanges();
```

When the user scans each item to add to the physical pallet an Item Transaction is created:

```
                        ItemTransaction itemTransaction = new ItemTransaction
                        {
                            transactionIdFK = _selectedTransaction.id,
                            LotCode = itemLotCode,
                            workCenter = workCenter,
                            RollNumber = rollNumber + 1,
                            Shift = shiftNumber,
                            EntryDateTime = DateTime.Now
                        };                            
                        myContext.ItemTransactions.Add(itemTransaction); //error occurs here
                        myContext.SaveChanges();
```

The transactionIdFK is the id created when adding the Pallet transaction.

Once the pallet meets a certain quantity a new pallet is created with the same product code. The user begins scanning new items and everything works fine. If they choose to change the product code the user must select a new one, whereby a new transaction is created successfully. However when the user scans a new item I receive the **The property 'id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.** error even though I am not tampering with the Id.

[image: Entity Model Diagram]

Comment: does `itemTransaction` have a property that references to `Transaction` entity?

Comment: Actually, update your question to provide the defined entity model types and entire method scopes that can be used to reproduce this.. in respect to providing a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). ... my thought here is that a one-many relationship is defined and is an aspect of these types (and their usage) here.  also, are you using database-first or code/model-first approach to EF6?

Comment: Brett Caswell  -The Transaction.id has an association with the ItemTransaction.transactionidFK. I am using database first approach.

Comment: alrighty, in the second method.. is `_selectedTransaction` an entity (retrieved from `DbSet<Transaction>` as a tracked `Transaction` type) or is it a `Transaction` type instance that is not being tracked by the framework (hence not an entity)?

Comment: You just solved it. It was a static class that held a public variable of type Transaction that I used between forms and I was updating the Id to -1 when clearing it. I removed it and now it is working. Thank you very much Bret Caswell.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution.  I was going to suggest retrieving and assigning a `Transaction` entity to the navigation property `Transaction` on this `ItemTransaction` instance before you add it to content, **OR** consider adding new instances of `ItemTransaction` (like the one above) to the navigation property `ItemTransactions` on a `Transaction` entity.